# What is the Google Apps Script equivalent of a Node Buffer object?

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, encryption, hex, cryptojs

Node.js [Fiddle](http://tpcg.io/XaQgOKdB):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let secret = 'my_secret';
let message = 'my_message';

let signer = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret)
const signature = signer.update(message).digest('base64');
console.log(signature); 
//signature = DWpafZMnI4PT5v0jdidFtU5qoh3fsvUKnaOga/Y2Nzy/tvsx1F9p61SjE+hlRQ97y/LMmBkG39IyL5Ja46bJlw==

// ***** Use Hex Buffer instead of string - same result
let message_buffer = Buffer.from(message); //<Buffer 6d 79 5f 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65>
let signer_from_buffer = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret)
const signature_from_buffer = signer_from_buffer.update(message_buffer).digest('base64');
console.log(signature_from_buffer); 
// signature = DWpafZMnI4PT5v0jdidFtU5qoh3fsvUKnaOga/Y2Nzy/tvsx1F9p61SjE+hlRQ97y/LMmBkG39IyL5Ja46bJlw==
```

and in Google Apps Script:

```
var secret =  'my_secret';
var message = 'my_message';

var signature_hash = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, message, secret);
var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(signature_hash);
Logger.log(signature);
//signature = DWpafZMnI4PT5v0jdidFtU5qoh3fsvUKnaOga/Y2Nzy/tvsx1F9p61SjE+hlRQ97y/LMmBkG39IyL5Ja46bJlw==

// Use Hex Array instead of string - different result
var message_buffer = ["6d", "79", "5f", "6d", "65", "73", "73", "61", "67", "65"];
var signature_hash_from_buffer = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, message_buffer , secret);
var signature_from_buffer = Utilities.base64Encode(signature_hash_from_buffer );
Logger.log(signature_from_buffer );
//signature_from_buffer = gGK0Y/KytE+8ZKWs/og1VQ1wMdPnoFmJMCHGpKdi+QODFwykqvDK5qJwgzZrr1b1g5050j9r8jpfXlM2ZA+3qQ==
```

So I know my Crypto process is working correctly.  The problem is, I am starting from the Hex Array, so I want to be able to get the same result.  I can't figure out what kind of Object the Node Buffer is, and how to translate that to Google Apps Script.

Comment: That's not a hexarray. It's just a array of strange strings

Comment: @themaster Correct.  It's an array of strings that matches the hex values of the Node Hex Buffer.  My question is what do I need to do with that array of strings to get the same result as the Node version?  It contains all the same information as the Node Buffer - but I don't know what format it should be in to make it work in the Apps Script functions.  The functions themselves work the same if I start with a regular text string.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that they are strings. If  indeed, they are,  they can be converted by byte array numbers((-127,128)) using `parseInt(character,16)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html),

> Buffer objects are used to represent a fixed-length sequence of bytes. Many Node.js APIs support Buffers.

> The Buffer class is a subclass of JavaScript's `Uint8Array` class and extends it with methods that cover additional use cases. Node.js APIs accept plain Uint8Arrays wherever Buffers are supported as well.

There is no direct support of `Buffer`

- Apps script supports [`Byte Array` from `Blob`s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getbytes). So  it is possible to emulate `Buffer.from`
- At Google Apps script, `Utilities.newBlob(str).getBytes()` returns [`Int8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array). In order to convert unsigned hexadecimal array to the byte array for Google Apps Script, it is required to convert it to `Int8Array`.
- Apps script also directly supports [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

```
const Buffer={from: str => Utilities.newBlob(str).getBytes()};
var message_buffer = Buffer.from(message);
var signature_hash_from_buffer = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, message_buffer , Buffer.from(secret));//modified as well
```

Comment: In this case, it's `Int8Array`. At Google Apps Script, `getBytes()` returns Int8Array which is an array of twos-complement 8-bit signed integers. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I modified it and also, I added one more sample script in my answer. If these might help to understand about the flow, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you. I just added that `Uint8Array` is also supported by default like `new Uint8Array()`, since node's `Buffer` is based on it, It might be relevant.

Comment: Yes. I agree with it.

Comment: Very helpful explanations - both solutions work as expected - thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve `DWpafZMnI4PT5v0jdidFtU5qoh3fsvUKnaOga/Y2Nzy/tvsx1F9p61SjE+hlRQ97y/LMmBkG39IyL5Ja46bJlw==` from `["6d", "79", "5f", "6d", "65", "73", "73", "61", "67", "65"]` using Google Apps Script.

At Google Apps Script, `getBytes()` returns Int8Array which is an array of twos-complement 8-bit signed integers. So in this case, at first, it is requierd to convert from `["6d", "79", "5f", "6d", "65", "73", "73", "61", "67", "65"]` to Int8Array. And when the byte array is used for `Utilities.computeHmacSignature`, `secret` is required to be also converted to the byte array. About this, it has already been mentioned by TheMaster's answer. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63642261)

Above points are reflected to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var secret =  'my_secret';
  var message_buffer = ["6d", "79", "5f", "6d", "65", "73", "73", "61", "67", "65"];
  
  // Convert message_buffer (Unsigned hexadecimal array) to Int8Array.
  var message = message_buffer.map(e => parseInt(e[0], 16).toString(2).length == 4 ? parseInt(e, 16) - 256: parseInt(e, 16));
  
  var signature_hash = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, message, Utilities.newBlob(secret).getBytes());
  var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(signature_hash);
  Logger.log(signature);
  // DWpafZMnI4PT5v0jdidFtU5qoh3fsvUKnaOga/Y2Nzy/tvsx1F9p61SjE+hlRQ97y/LMmBkG39IyL5Ja46bJlw==
}
```

#### Other pattern:

As other pattern, in this pattern, `message_buffer` is converted to Unit8Array, and Unit8Array is converted to Int8Array, and then, the Int8Array is used with `Utilities.computeHmacSignature()`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var secret =  'my_secret';
  var message_buffer = ["6d", "79", "5f", "6d", "65", "73", "73", "61", "67", "65"];
  
  // Convert message_buffer (Unsigned hexadecimal array) to Unit8Array.
  var unit8Array = message_buffer.map(e => parseInt(e, 16));
  
  // Convert Unit8Array to Int8Array.
  var int8Array = [...new Int8Array(Uint8Array.from(unit8Array).buffer)];

  var signature_hash = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, int8Array, Utilities.newBlob(secret).getBytes());
  var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(signature_hash);
  Logger.log(signature);
  // DWpafZMnI4PT5v0jdidFtU5qoh3fsvUKnaOga/Y2Nzy/tvsx1F9p61SjE+hlRQ97y/LMmBkG39IyL5Ja46bJlw==
}
```

#### References:

- [Int8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array)

  > The Int8Array typed array represents an array of twos-complement 8-bit signed integers.
- [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

  > The Uint8Array typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers.
- [computeHmacSignature(algorithm, value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsignaturealgorithm,-value,-key)